# How to Debug Error 400: Bad Request? (PHP)

Tags: php, apache, logging

Occassionally, I attempt to upload an mp3 to my server, it gets a "400: bad request" error. It sometimes works, sometime doesn't. I want to debug this!

I was wondering if there was a way to log the error via php, and the more verbose reason why it is a bad request? I've searched and cannot find a solution. thanks.

Comment: Your webserver log is first place.

Comment: How is PHP involved in your upload operation?

Comment: The `4xx` HTTP errors are client errors. Either the client requested a non-existing resource (`404`) or it is not authorized to see the resource (`401...403`) or the HTTP request is incomplete or doesn't look like a HTTP request at all (`400`) and so on. If the PHP code doesn't generate the `400` responses then the PHP code doesn't even run for those requests (and there is nothing to debug). In this case the code is generated by Apache and it doesn't invoke the PHP interpreter because it didn't receive a valid HTTP request.

Comment: The Wikipedia page of the [HTTP response codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) provides a clue that could help you: *"400 Bad Request: The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, size too large..."* -- I don't know about Apache but PHP uses a (configurable) upper limit for the size of the uploaded files it accepts.

Answer (score -1):

The first place to look would be your Apache logs. Assuming you're on Linux, these would be somewhere like `/var/log/apache/access_log` for the access log, and `/var/log/apache/error_log` for the error log (although as George Appleton pointed out below, bad requests won't be recorded in the error log). You can also write messages to the error log with the [error_log function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php).

You could also look into using [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) to debug your PHP code.

Comment: Bad requests aren't an error so won't appear in your apache error_log

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton You're right, and I've updated my answer accordingly